# Difference between two pull codes in gromacs (SMD)

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs

My molecule is aligned along x-axis, and I want to pull this molecule along x-axis with one end defined as the first pull group, and another end as the second pull group. I have two pull codes, which I think should produce the same result. However, I am a bit confused now since they are not essentially giving me the same result. Can anyone tell me what's the difference between these two pull codes, and which one is the correct one to use while pulling the molecule along x-axis.

This is the first one with distance defined as the pull_coord1_geometry.

```
pull                     = yes
pull-ngroups             = 2
pull-group1-name         = end1
pull-group2-name         = end2
pull-ncoords             = 1
pull-coord1-geometry     = distance
pull-coord1-groups       = 1 2
pull-coord1-type         = umbrella
pull-coord1-k            = 5000.0
pull-coord1-rate         = 0.002
pull-coord1-dim          = Y N N
pull-print-ref-value     = yes
pull-coord1_start        = yes
```

And this is the second one with the direction defined as the pull_coord1_geometry.

```
pull                     = yes
pull-ngroups             = 2
pull-group1-name         = end1
pull-group2-name         = end2
pull-ncoords             = 1
pull-coord1-geometry     = direction
pull-coord1-groups       = 1 2
pull-coord1-type         = umbrella
pull-coord1-k            = 5000.0
pull-coord1-rate         = 0.002
pull-coord1-vec          = 1 0 0
pull-print-ref-value     = yes
pull-coord1_start        = yes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very common to pull along the direction of the vector connecting the two pull groups, i.e., `pull-coord1-geometry = distance`. If you want to pull in the direction of a specific vector, then you should use `pull-coord1-geometry = direction`. But this will create an extra torque in the system unless you pull against a fixed orientation group. If your reference group does not have a fixed orientation, then you should use `pull-coord1-geometry = distance-relative`. In the case of `pull-coord1-geometry = distance-relative`, you should supply four groups instead of two.